# Installation of pyautogui Module fails (I am using python 3.5 32 bit)

Tags: pyautogui

Please help. I type pip install pyautogui at the command prompt.
The process begins then stalls. Here is what happens:

```
C:\Users\alexS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Scripts>pip install
pyautogui
Collecting pyautogui
  Using cached PyAutoGUI-0.9.33.zip
Collecting pymsgbox (from pyautogui)
  Using cached PyMsgBox-1.0.3.zip
Collecting PyTweening>=1.0.1 (from pyautogui)
  Using cached PyTweening-1.0.3.zip
Collecting Pillow (from pyautogui)
  Using cached Pillow-3.3.1-cp35-cp35m-win32.whl
Collecting pyscreeze (from pyautogui)
  Using cached PyScreeze-0.1.8.zip
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\alexS\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-1kn1qve4\pyscreeze\se
tup.py", line 6, in <module>
        version=__import__('pyscreeze').__version__,
      File "C:\Users\alexS\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-1kn1qve4\pyscreeze\py
screeze\__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
        from PIL import Image
    ImportError: No module named 'PIL'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\alexS
\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-1kn1qve4\pyscreeze\

C:\Users\alexS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Scripts>
```

Answer (score 0):

Install the `Image` module first by doing:

```
$ pip install Image
```

Then retry installing `pyautogui` again

This answer is based on experience.

Comment: Thanks very much. pip install PILLOW worked as well.

Answer (score 0):

This has been fixed as of 0.9.34, so you should be able to just install it now. Just run `pip install -U pyautogui`